Python: Open group dataset with CRS, where top-level variables store CRS
I have a set of NetCDF files that I'm converting to multi-band geotiffs. I'm using xarray to load the data from the NetCDF and rasterio to convert each band to a geotiff before combining them all into a single geotiff.
The trick is, the crs variable is only available at the top-level. But group variables still use crs for grid_mapping. How can I make the crs variable available to the group variables?
# bands = [{ 'band_variable': 'var_a' }, { 'band_variable': 'var_b', 'band_group': 'a_group' }]
def netcdf_to_geotiff(in_netcdf, bands):
    # This dict is just for the simplified example - this is actually created 
    # programatically elsewhere in my code. It's the opening/converting techniques,
    # which are used here, that I'm concerned about in this question.
    dataset_dict = {
        'top_level': xr.open_dataset(
            in_netcdf,
            cache=False,
            mask_and_scale=True,
            decode_coords="all",
        ),
        'a_group': xr.open_dataset(
            in_netcdf,
            cache=False,
            mask_and_scale=True,
            decode_coords="all",
            group='a_group',
        )
    }

    input_crs = dataset_dict['top_level'].crs

    for band in bands:
        band_group = band['band_group'] if 'band_group' in band else 'top_level'
        netcdf_dataset = dataset_dict[band_group]

        band_geotiff = convert_band_to_geotiff(
            dataset=netcdf_dataset, 
            variable=band['band_variable'],
            input_crs_wkt=input_crs.crs_wkt,
            output_file='{}.tif'.format(band['band_variable'])
        )
        
    # geotiff merging, etc



def convert_band_to_geotiff(dataset, variable, input_crs_wkt, output_file):
    value_array = dataset[variable]

    value_array = value_array.fillna(np.nan)

    value_array.rio.set_spatial_dims(
        x_dim='longitude',
        y_dim='latitude',
        inplace=True,
    )

    value_array.rio.write_crs(input_crs_wkt, inplace=True)
    value_array.rio.write_nodata(np.nan, inplace=True)

    value_array.rio.to_raster(
        raster_path=output_file,
        driver="GTiff",
        colorinterp=[rasterio.enums.ColorInterp.gray],
    )

The script as-is gives the the warnings:

When opening the a group dataset: UserWarning: Variable(s) referenced in grid_mapping not in variables: ['crs']
When converting a group dataset to a raster: NotGeoreferencedWarning: The given matrix is equal to Affine.identity or its flipped counterpart. GDAL may ignore this matrix and save no geotransform without raising an error. This behavior is somewhat driver-specific.

The original NetCDF file looks something like this:
netcdf stuff.nc {
  dimensions:
    lat = UNLIMITED;   // (4932 currently)
    lon = UNLIMITED;   // (3564 currently)
  variables:
    double lat(lat=4932);
      :long_name = "latitude";
      :units = "degrees_north";
      :standard_name = "latitude";

    double lon(lon=3564);
      :long_name = "longitude";
      :units = "degrees_east";
      :standard_name = "longitude";

    float var_a(lat=4932, lon=3564);
      :grid_mapping = "crs";

    long crs;
      :grid_mapping_name = "latitude_longitude";
      :longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.0; // double
      :semi_major_axis = 6378137.0; // double
      :inverse_flattening = 298.257223563; // double
      :crs_wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\" ...very long wkt";

  group: a_group {
    variables:
      float var_b(lat=4932, lon=3564);
        :grid_mapping = "crs";
        :units = "1";

  }

  // global attributes:
  :geospatial_lat_min = "some_value";
  :geospatial_lat_max = "some_value";
  :geospatial_lon_min = "some_value";
  :geospatial_lon_max = "some_value";
  :geospatial_lat_resolution = "1 arcsecond";
  :geospatial_lon_resolution = "1 arcsecond";
}

If I change the way I open group datasets to use decode_coords=None, the first warning isn't raised, but the code then throws an error, not a warning:
ValueError: failed to prevent overwriting existing key grid_mapping in attrs. This is probably an encoding field used by xarray to describe how a variable is serialized. To proceed, remove this key from the variable's attributes manually.
It's possible to delete grid_mapping from the var_b dataset before converting it to a tif, but that seems wrong. Is it?
I'm not sure what the best/correct way to handle this is. Can I make crs available to var_b, even though var_b is nested in a group? Do I need to? Or can I safely ignore the warnings?
